# Via block get custom type image or display default

Tags: magento2, image

I want to display my new product image type in my phtml.

I use :

> echo $block->getImage($product, "custom_type_image")->toHtml()

That work, but all my product didn't have an image with this type, so I would like, if no image was found, that display default image like :

> echo $block->getImage($product, "product_base_image")->toHtml()

How to check ?

I can't check

```
if $block->getImage($product, "custom_type_image")->toHtml()
```

is null because, if it doesn't succeed to find my picture, it create one as custom_type_image.jpg (which doesn't exist, so the picture is broken)

Comment: what if you check `$product->getCustomTypeImage();` ?

Comment: Indeed, it was easy but I did'nt think about this method, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check it by `$product->getCustomTypeImage();`

As it is a product attribute, it will give you value.